# computing dot product of two vectors without the coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I solve the following three questions, without the knowing the actual values of the vectors?

1. The dot product between $\vec{u}$ and $-5\vec{u}$.
2. Dot product between $\vec{u}$ and $2\vec{v}$.
3. Dot product between $\vec{u}+4\vec{v}$ and $\vec{u}-4\vec{v}$.

I kind of got to $\vec{u_1}(-5\vec{u_1})+ \vec{u_2}(-5\vec{u_2}) +\vec{u_n}(-5\vec{u_n})$
which would be $-5\vec{u_1^2} - 5\vec{u_2^2} - 5\vec{u_n^2}$. How else would I be able to compute without the actual coordinates of the vectors?

Edit: If not possible, what is missing?

Comment: The first equation tells you the length of $u$ (and only that).  The third equation (given the first) tells you then length of $v$ (and only that).  The second equation tells you the angle between $u$ and $v$ (and only that) by the relationship between dot product and cosine.  That's a lot of information, but it doesn't completely characterize either vector.

Comment: You’ll need $u\cdot u=\|u\|^2$, $v\cdot v=\|v\|^2$, and $u\cdot v$. Then, you can apply symmetry and bilinearity of the dot product to find the dot products. But currently the problem is unsolveable.

Comment: You don't need coordinates for vectors, but you do need more information. What else did they give you that you “forgot” to include?

Comment: I tried to rewrite your post using LaTeX, but there is a clear error there since $\vec{u} \cdot \vec{u}$ is not equal to $\vec{u}^2$ nor $\vec{u^2}$, but rather we should indicate it as $||u||^2$ (i.e., the magnitude of $u$ squared).

Comment: @Marco You also omitted the dots?

Comment: I haven't seen the dots in the original post, but yes... they should be if we wish to indicate the terms between the second one and the $n$-th, I guess.

Comment: @marco appreciate the edits,

Comment: @user22910453 You are welcome, try to use LaTeX by yourself next time and, please, add those "cdots" there if you think that they should be included ;)

Comment: So what information have you not included?

Comment: Cof, cof... ehm, cof, cof (just joking).